# Can I combine documents while both keep their own format?

Tags: latex

For my MSc. I'm writing up a manuscript using the publisher's templates. This document also has to be included in the thesis report. I'd like to insert the manuscript in the report without the format of the manuscript changing. How can I do this?

I've seen some examples of the standalone package but they all talk about *including document B into document A while both keep the formatting of A*. What I'm looking for is essentially a workaround to using two document classes.

Comment: Have a look at the `pdfpages` package